# My rabbit lost his claw

Tags: rabbits, injury

My rabbit lost a claw, I found it on the ground. I checked his feet and it seems to be the dewclaw on his front left foot. There is no blood on the claw or on his foot so I'm unsure how to treat it.

He hasn't been limping and he had been eating and running around the room like normal until I found it (I am keeping him in his cage for now). Any ideas on what I should do?

Thanks so much!